# Build configuration for dynamically referenced projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I have an ASP.NET project that is included in multiple solutions. In each solution I'd like a different *unreferenced* project to be included in the ASP.NET project's build output. The solutions look like this:

- Foo.sln

  - *WebApp.csproj*
  - Foo.csproj
- Bar.sln

  - *WebApp.csproj*
  - Bar.csproj

Ideally, this would work even when debugging with F5. I tried doing this with build configurations, but deviating from the typical 'Debug' and 'Release' seems brittle when working within Visual Studio. Is there a typical way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer: I don't think this is a very good idea to do but it seems like it can be done.**

To test this solution I created two projects. ConsoleApplication1 and ClassLibrary1. ConsoleApplication1 does not have a reference (that is visible in Visual Studio) to ClassLibary1 but when building ConsoleApplication1 from Visual Studio it will build then copy the ClassLibary1.dll to the bin folder of ConsoleApplication1.

To import the target file you will go ahead and add this line to the project that you want to build the unreferenced project. This path will be relative to the current project so in my case the target file was at the root of my solution. Make sure you add this after the line `<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />` because `unreferenced.target` relies on targets that are setup in `Microsoft.CSharp.targets`.

```
<Import Project="..\unreferenced.target" />
```

Then you will go ahead and create a file name unreferenced.target and add the contents below to the file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
 <!-- Start another msbuild task to build your unreferenced project -->
 <Target Name="BuildBeforeResolveReferences" BeforeTargets="BeforeResolveReferences">
    <MSBuild
      BuildInParallel="False"
      Projects="$(SolutionDir)ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj"
      RunEachTargetSeparately="True"
      StopOnFirstFailure="False"
      UnloadProjectsOnCompletion="False">
    </MSBuild>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="CopyUnreferencedProjectOutput" AfterTargets="Build">
    <!-- This item group is here because we do not want it evaluated by msbuild until the ClassLibrary1.csproj has been compiled and its output is in its output directory -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <!-- Gets a list of all files at the OutputPath that end in .dll if you need the pdbs remove the .dll -->
      <!-- To maintain folder structure in the bin folder use <SourceFiles Include="..\ClassLibary1\@(OutputPath)**\*.dll" /> the double ** is a recursive wild card and will look through all directorys -->
      <SourceFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\ClassLibrary1\$(OutputPath)*.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <!-- To make sure the copy maintains folder structure switch it to this copy -->
    <!-- <Copy SourceFiles="@(SourceFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(SourceFiles -> '$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)$(OutputPath)%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" /> -->
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(SourceFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(OutputPath)" />
  </Target>

  <!-- Cleans up all the files when clean is called -->
  <Target Name="CleanUnreferenceProjectOutput" BeforeTargets="Clean">
    <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Removed the .dll from the end of this to clean up the pdbs  as well -->
      <SourceFiles Include="$(SolutionDir)\ClassLibrary1\$(OutputPath)*" />
      <SourceFiles Include="$(SolutionDir)\ConsoleApplication1\$(OutputPath)*.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Delete Files="@(SourceFiles)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

I think this is the best that can be done. You could extend this to have a list of projects that are not referenced but you want to build but for this example I just left it at one.

EDIT 2: Before getting to the current solution I did extensive research into injecting the reference into the ProjectReference itemgroup before assemblies were resolved. It can be done but you have to set the property `BuildInVisualStudio` to false because otherwise when the msbuild conditions are evaluted in the `ResolveProjectReferences` target in `Microsoft.Common.Current.targets` you will select a MSBuild task that only runs the `GetManifest` target. I was able to get the solution to build but given my lack of knowledge on what setting `BuildInVisualStudio` to false entails I opted for the solution above. Also I added a task for cleaning up the files that were moved to the bin folders because clean will only cleanup what `{ProjectName}{ProjectExtension}FileListAbsoluteText.txt` in the obj folder of your project.

EDIT: After doing some more research into the solution below it will only work from the command line. I am currently looking into why this is occuring.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a typical way of doing what you are asking for (from IDE), but you have an options to accomplish this manually by editing the *.*proj files.

Each project will emit output (*.dll, *.exe, app.config, etc), and it will be copied to the folder specified in the **$(OutputPath)** property (internally it will use OutDir property). If you will build a solution, you will have the **$(SolutionDir)** property, as well as **$(SolutionName)**. So, you can define new msbuild project, which will be referenced by the other ones, and you can set the property $(OutputPath) so that every output will go into one folder (let call it Common.props):

```
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SolutionDir Condition=" '$(SolutionDir)' == '' ">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)<SolutionDir>
    <SolutionName Condition=" '$(SolutionName)' == '' " >DefaultSlnName</SolutionName>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)$(SolutionName)\bin\$(Configuration)</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

After that, you should import that project by your other projects - *.*proj (you should specify correct path to the project):

```
<Import Project="..\Common.props"  Condition="Exists('..\Common.props')" />
```

Using common **$(OutputPath)** property will place all of your binaries to the one folder - this should help to resolve your task.

Comment: Are you saying the projects being built will have to reference this new project? That wouldn't solve the problem because the projects being built are agnostic to these dependencies.

Comment: This is msbuild project, it is not a normal csharp project. You will not add a reference in terms of `ProjectReference`, or just a binary `Reference`. You will import some common properties, which will be evaluated depending on the solution beign built.